# Setting up a PHP and SQL Website

Tags: php, mysql, web, hosting

so I've recently finished a course on web development, and completed a final project that functioned on my personal Apache Web Server and MySQL Database (MariaDB) through XAMPP. I should note that the site works perfectly as expected on the Apache. I'm interested in having this site hosted so that others can access it as well. (I've never had any sites hosted before, even static ones, and I'd like to do this to experiment). I've tried searching the web for hosting sites with PHP connected to SQL databases and could not find a solution. What I'd like to do is set up a site where the PHP is able to communicate with the SQL db and update realtime so that all visitors can see the changes.

From what I've gathered, I believe that I'll have to host the SQL db from a site that hosts them and separately have another site host my php site. I'm assuming that in my Database Adaptor function, I'll have to change the value of "host" in $db to connect to the SQL db being hosted rather than direct it "home". Is this correct? or am I going about this completely wrong?

This is the database adaptor function I used:

```
class DatabaseAdaptor {
private $DB;
public function __construct() {
    $db = 'mysql:dbname=planner;host=127.0.0.1;charset=utf8';
    $user = 'root';
    $password = '';

    try {
        $this->DB = new PDO ( $db, $user, $password );
        $this->DB->setAttribute ( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
    } catch ( PDOException $e ) {
        echo ('Error establishing Connection');
        exit ();
    }
}
```

If I'm going about this completely wrong, could you please lead me in the right direction. I've read a little about WordPress and it seems like they have some compatibility with php and databases, are they what I'm looking for?

In addition, what sites would you recommend for hosting php sites or sql databases?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right, you have to change this:

```
$db = 'mysql:dbname=planner;host=127.0.0.1;charset=utf8';
$user = 'root';
$password = '';
```

to the one given by your hosting company. There are various hosting companies that provide PHP and MySql hosting.

Answer (score 0):

When you subscribe to a Hosting Provider, they usually have a knowledge base or guidelines on how you would setup your website through the Control Panel. From there, you will be able to setup database(s), (S)FTP to upload your PHP files to your (public) directory, and even setup email(s). There are a lot of (PHP) hosting providers it's up to you which to choose. Here are a few:

- [DreamHost](https://www.dreamhost.com/r.cgi?534922)
- [SiteGround](https://www.siteground.com/php-hosting.htm)
- [HostGator](https://www.hostgator.com/web-hosting)
- [Linode](https://www.linode.com/pricing)
- [GoDaddy](https://www.godaddy.com/hosting/web-hosting)

Or you might want to try a free (sandbox) from [Heroku](https://www.heroku.com/php)?

Happy hunting!